# response_type id_token token in authorization request produce this error: callback URL does not match with the provided callback URL

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using the WSO2 Identity Server 5.9. In my demo applications for login, use this link

```
https://IP:9443/oauth2/authorize?scope=openid&response_type=id_token%20token&redirect_uri=http://IP:PORT&client_id=OLTBkgsti_bkfEHnB8Tqi_q64cka&nonce=abc&prompt=consent
```

For authorization request used **id_token token** as the response_type

when i use this : response_type=id_token%20token

does not work recovery username and password, generating this error:

```
Configured callback URL does not match with the provided callback URL: %s in the request
```

apparently the blank %20 affects the recovery functionality

Any ideas to fix this behavior?,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The browser replaces the blank with %20

Comment: url in the documentation: &response_type = id_token token, a space between both words

Comment: if I put response_type=id_token&... it works fine recovery password and recovery username